# How transition smoothly multiple guitar recordings?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, recording

I play folk music with my guitar and I am trying to record some tracks.

In these songs there are many chords progression so my first attempt was to record them separately and then recreate the right sequence.

My problem is that you can hear like a "break" between the single recordings, they don't match up properly and you can definitely recognize they are not played in just one take.

For instance, how did he record a song like this?

Only one take or there's some trick I am not aware of?

Comment: Did you try to export the tracks when you got the "breaks"? I think if you place it right and record it in the same environment, you'll get it right after you export it.

Comment: I am not talking about connecting separate tracks, the problem is about different parts of the same song, like transit from the verse to the chorus section. Of course I am recording with the same settings and the same environment.

Comment: Are you recording each attempt to a new track? If so you can usually cut or cross-fade at the transition point later. One trick is to not make the edits at the transition between chords - get the transition clean, even if you have to play just half a bar before, then make the chord change. You can then make your edit a bit earlier… where no-one will hear it.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if we had an example of a recording that you have made where you can let us hear the problem, instead of a recording of what you're trying to achieve. Are you able to play the whole piece through live even if you make a mistake or three? If not then you might need more practice with it before you try to record it.

Comment: Are you recording to a metronome click-track that you listen to in your headphones while you play your guitar into the microphone? Recording each phrase to the same rigid tempo with a click track will be essential.

Comment: I listened to the recording you included in your post.  It sure sounds like he just played the whole thing through, as one would do in a concert performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- **Play it in one take.**  I won't get into your own abilities, or why you need to record sections separately, however for thousands of years musicians have played (and still play!) full, complete pieces without needing to stop and change.  It happens more than you think in modern music styles, and some artists pride themselves on playing their instrument and songs.
- **Edit sections.**  Up until 35 or so years ago you couldn't do this.  I've done it recently, and it is simple to do within a DAW environment.  It is possible to create a composite, but your editing skills may not be sufficient to produce what you want.  It takes a little bit of effort and practice, and there will be plenty of web resources to help you out.  Making sure you play to a metronome may help you, but it's by no means obligatory.

Though, what I will say is that if your music is just designed to be recording only then composite building is fine, however if you are looking for you or someone else to play live, then really you need to put in the practice to learn to play start to finish.  Your ability, and your recordings, will be much better off.